# PowerBI_Change Blank Value in a matrix with something

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have this table in PowerBI and i want to change the blank values with somthing like "others" tried a new column with a If(isBlank) and its not working.
[MatrixTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSSMY.png)

Comment: PBI doesn't handle ragged hierarchies very well so you will need to write a lot of code. https://www.daxpatterns.com/hierarchies/

Comment: Have to use the isinscope function ?